# Remove/Disable USB Host controller driver

Tags: linux

Am a quite naive user of linux. I would like to know whether there is a way in which I can remove/disable the USB Host controller driver from the kernel, without kernel compilation..Am using a custom system which has linux in it (Fedora)

If not, how should i go about recompiling the kernel to have this module disabled.

Comment: I am sure you can do it by excluding the required driver / USB component, however, you may find it a lot easier to disable USB functions through the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a line similar to the following to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist your-mod-name
```

and remove it from the currently running system:

```
modprobe -r your-mod-name
```